I'm losing power in high gears
I have power in 1,2,3rd great but when go into 4,5 gears fella like losing all the power goes high revs and loses spread any heap much appreciated

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What is the year/make/model of the vehicle in question? Is it a standard or automatic transmission?

Since you haven't answered Paulster's question about your vehicle after 24 hours, I'm going to assume that you are driving something with a manual transmission because you are talking about 5 individual gear speeds.
You probably have a problem with your clutch. If the friction surfaces of the clutch are contaminated with oil or if they are simply worn out, the vehicle will seem to work fine (for now) in the lower gears, but the clutch will slip in the higher gears, resulting in suddenly higher rpm and seemingly a lack of power.
If the friction surfaces are worn, then sooner or later even the lower gears will slip and you will not be able to move the vehicle at all. If you want to keep the vehicle, the clutch needs to be diagnosed as good or bad and probably replaced.
If a bad oil leak is causing the clutch slippage, the leak needs to be repaired, then the clutch diagnosed as good or bad.

Thanks that ls a great help I will have a look thanks a lot
